# How can I rebuild the faac package to get mp4/m4a support and higher bitrates?

Tags: packaging, patch, mp4, aac, m4a

The copy of faac under Ubuntu Trusty Tahr 14.04 has 2 limitations:

- It does not have mp4/m4a support
- It cannot use high bitrates

How can I rebuild faac, using correct Debian packaging techniques, to overcome these problems?

**References:**

- [ffmpeg options: -acodec libfaac -ab 192k produce 150kbit files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19994/ffmpeg-options-acodec-libfaac-ab-192k-produce-150kbit-files)
- [Why doesn't the faac package support mp4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382703/why-doesnt-the-faac-package-support-mp4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to rebuild the Trusty faac package and solve both of these issues as follows:

- Support mp4/m4a by building against an *external* libmp4v2
- Use higher bitrates by patching faac

Use the following steps:

1. First install the required build dependencies, some build tools and the new dependency of libmp4v2:

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep faac
   sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot devscripts libmp4v2-dev
   ```
2. Then make a build directory, get a patch to allow higher bitrates with faac and apply that patch:

   ```
   mkdir $HOME/Desktop/faac_build && cd $HOME/Desktop/faac_build
   apt-get source faac
   wget http://www.andrews-corner.org/patches/A00-bitrates.patch
   cd faac-1.28
   patch -p1 < ../A00-bitrates.patch
   ```
3. Appropriately change the packaging information:

   ```
   debchange -i
   ```

   My own editing of this file is as follows:

   ```
    faac (1.28-7) unstable; urgency=low

      * Patch to allow higher bitrates
      * Compile against external libmp4v2-dev

     -- andrew <andrew@corinth>  Sat, 27 Feb 2016 20:21:02 +1100
   ```

   It is important to make the version number incrementally greater than the repository version or your next update might overwrite your new package!
4. Make proper documentation of the patch:

   ```
     dpkg-source --commit
   ```

   Add a brief description of the purpose of the patch in the dialogue box that opens with this command.
5. And finally rebuild and install the package:

   ```
   debuild -us -uc -i -I
   sudo debi
   ```

And now you have access to higher bitrates with faac and you can output to an appropriately tagged m4a/mp4 container!

**References:**

- [Updating A Deb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpdatingADeb)